# definite integral area help

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, area

Write the definite integral that computes the area of the region bounded by the graphs of $y=\sqrt{1+x^3}$, $y=\frac{1}{2}x+2$ and $y=0$.

I'm very confused because I graphed it on my calculator and it looked like it was infinite because the curve wasn't closed.. is it infinite or am I doing something completely wrong?

Comment: Looks to me like it should be `x=0`; certainly the square root is not defined for `x < -1`.

Comment: yeah I agree with you. I'm going to ask my teacher if that was a typo

Comment: @sloth1111: see my answer. I think we can solve your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that 
$$y=\sqrt{1+x^3}$$
is defined only in $1+x^3\ge0\iff x\ge -1$.

See [the graph](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y=%281%2bx%5E3%29%5E%281/2%29%20and%20y=%281/2%29x%2b2).

So, if we divide the region into two small regions, then we can get an answer.
$$\int_{-4}^{-1} \left(\frac 12x+2\right)dx+\int_{-1}^{2}\left(\frac 12x+2-\sqrt{1+x^3}\right)dx$$

Comment: ohhhhhhhh!! i didn't even think of dividing the area into 2 distinct pieces. that makes a lot of sense looking at the restrictions with the radical! thank you!

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: @mathlove. Fortunately, they did not ask for the value. The antiderivative of Sqrt[1+x^3] is just awful to me. Do you know any change of variables which would make it nice ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: A good point! I have no idea. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral_%28-1%29%5E%282%29%28%281%2F2%29x%2B2-%281%2Bx%5E3%29%5E%281%2F2%29%29dx

Comment: @mathlove. Just for fun, ask WA just the antiderivative !

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: Yeah, I've already seen it. it's wonderfully messy.